# Using Depth First Search to go through a 2D list in python

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I am trying to create a DFS algorithm to search a 2D List character maze in python but I am unsure as to how exactly to do it. The end goal is to find out as to whether or not the maze is solvable so I would return True if solvable and False otherwise.

Maze Key:
- 'S' start
- 'G' goal
- 'W' wall
- 'x' floor

***Example Maze***

x S W

x x W

x W G

x x x

Comment: Maybe this will help you start: https://towardsdatascience.com/depth-breath-first-search-matrix-traversal-in-python-with-interactive-code-back-to-basics-31f1eca46f55

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dfs+python+list